# Filter not working with ion-list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have a list with three dividers (today, this week, later) that i would like to populate with some events. I'am using filter to sort each event for each divider but I can't get it working. It does not filter anything. Any help ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Here is my html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Évènements à venir">
  <ion-content has-bouncing="false" has-tabs ="true" has-header="true">
    <ion-list>
     <div class="item item-calm item-divider">
    Aujourd'hui ()
  </div>
    <ion-item class="item item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-click="detail()" ng-repeat="soiree in test | filter:filterDay" type="item-text-wrap" >
        <img src={{}}>
        <h2>{{soiree.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{soiree.description}}</p>
        <i class="button icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i>
        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive"
                       ng-click="removeSoiree(soiree)">
      Supprimer
    </ion-option-button>
    </ion-item>
     <div class="item item-calm item-divider">
    Cette semaine ({{soireeWeekNumber}})
  </div>
  <ion-item class="item item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="soiree in test | filter:filterWeek" type="item-text-wrap">
        <img src={{}}>
        <h2>{{soiree.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{soiree.description}}</p>
        <i class="button icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And here is my filter and my controller:

```
.filter('filterDay', function() {
  return function(item) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    if (Math.abs(currentDate - item.date) <= 1000*60*60*24) return true
    else return false
    }
})

.filter('filterWeek', function() {
  return function(item) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    if (Math.abs(currentDate - item.date) > 1000*60*60*24 && Math.abs(item.date - currentDate) <= 7*1000*60*60*24) {
     return true
    } else {
     return false
    }}
})

.filter('filterFurther', function() {
  return function(item) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    if (Math.abs(item.date - currentDate) >= 7*1000*60*60*24) {
     return true
    } else {
     return false
    }}
})

.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicLoading, Soirees) {

  $scope.soirees = Soirees.all();
  $scope.test = [{papa: 1,date: new Date()},
  {papa: 2,date: new Date()},
  {papa: 3,date: new Date()}]

  $scope.detail = function() {
    $state.go('tab.detail')
  }
})
```

Comment: Looks like you have not used filter anywhere..then how will they work.

Comment: <ion-item class="item item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="soiree in test | filter:filterWeek" type="item-text-wrap">

Comment: can you add a fiddle or a plunkr?

Comment: Not sure how to do that! need to upload the whole project since it is ionic right ?

Comment: hmm, so it works with plain angular on browser but not in ionic on mobile?

Comment: No it is not working at all.

Comment: change to `ng-repeat="soiree in test | filterName" ...` and then have the filter function such that it takes in a list of objects (`test`) in your case and returns a filtered list.

Comment: So I should not return true or false anymore ? What is wrong with that ?

Comment: Could you please add example data for the list you'd like to filter? Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/0v83d0tt/) of your code. I've added ng-controller because of missing ui-router config but filtering is not working because of the missing data.

Comment: is $scope.test in my controller data you want ?